# Selecting TOP ranking through SQL in Unica

Tags: sql, sorting, ranking

I have a table with 2 columns; `sub_ID` and `RANK`.

All `sub_ID` are unique and there are around 100k and have all been given a `RANK` between 1 - 38 in the `RANK` column.

I am working in **Unica** or **IBM Campaign** where in a `SELECT` cell I need to enter raw SQL that only returns 5000 subscribers where it selects based on the `RANK` in preference for 38 and less.

Comment: Could you show us the queries you have tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately I am an SQL newbie so dont have any attempts so far...

Answer (score 1):

Use a sample process box. Limiting number of cells to 1 with number of records to 5000 and sorting based on rank column

Comment: This could be a better solution than writing a raw sql query while working with Unica.